# Is asking what houseplants are toxic to cats too much of a list question to ask?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions

I was thinking about asking a question asking what houseplants I should avoid getting, but it's pretty obvious it's a list question. What I'm not sure about is whether it will be okay because the list shouldn't ever change (at least not in our lifetimes), so it could become an aggregate list of plants toxic to cats.

What do you think? Too much of a list question that I should skip it? Or is it okay because it can possibly have a canonical answer?

Update: Asked to see how it would go [What plants should I not have around cats?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5662/481)

Comment: Not a lot of interest in addressing this in meta, so maybe just post it and see what happens?

Comment: Marked as completed, no apparent negative reaction to meta or main question.

Answer (score 2):

I think OK, because it going to be a stable list & it has a canonical answer.